# Android : Draw TextEdit(s) or TextView(s) when user enter number of them.[exp: 6 then draw 6 TextView]

Tags: android, dynamic, textview, android-edittext, android-linearlayout

Wantto ask user to enter number of TextEdit or ViewText and then draw them.
For-example user enter 7,then seven ViewText draw.I knew this is a suitable way but in my prgrm i cant change the whole structure,the i got this erro at:

```
    tv = new TextView(this);
```

and error is: "The constructor TextView(new View.OnClickListener(){}) is undefined".

i knew i have to do:

```
    implements OnClickListener
```

but i cant change the prgrm now.SO is there anyway to create TextView(or any View objct) without refrence it to 'layout' xml?

```
    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.myLL);
    for(int i=1 ; i<= 10 ; i++){
      TextView tv = new TextView(this);
      tv.setText("String/String/String");
      ll.addView(tv);
      }
```

*THANKS,,*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're adding the LinearLayout to itself. The last line should be `ll.addView(tv);`

Answer (score 0):

```
    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.myLL);
         for(int i=1 ; i<= 10 ; i++)
               {
                 TextView tv = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                 tv.setText("String/String/String");
                 ll.addView(tv);
               }
```

replace 'new TextView(**new**)' with 'new TextView(**getApplicationContext()**)' .