# Android : when i put 'addView(..) inside a forloop i got error..Here we go

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, tablelayout

Here the code sample:

```
     TableLayout ll = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.dyn_lyr);
```

also same with LinearLayout

```
    //LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.dyn_lyr);

    TextView tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.testEditText);
    tv1.setText("SomeTextGoesHere");

    for(int i=1 ; i<= 5 ; i++){
        ll.addView(tv1);
            }
```

the LinearLayout/Table is inside ScrollView!

Comment: You can't add the same instance of a view multiple times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create TextView Dynamically and add in ll...

```
for(int i=1 ; i<= 5 ; i++){
    TextView tv1 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    tv1.setText("SomeTextGoesHere");
    ll.addView(tv1);
}
```

Comment: Perfect:O ..   Problem-solved. Actually i knew i must create TextView onAir but i create my prgram without 'implements OnClickListener' and i gone that way...i used new TextView(*this*) here was my mess :|  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23199133/android-draw-textedits-or-textviews-when-user-enter-number-of-them-exp-6

Answer (score 0):

There is not enought info but I guess that Tv1 already has a parent . I guess that you should add new TextView every time . Try this one. Ok then create brand new TextView

```
  for(int i=1 ; i<= 5 ; i++){
       TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
       tv1.setText("SomeTextGoesHere");
       ll.addView(tv1);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `findViewById`, the resulting view is already a part of your layout and has a parent. Each view can only be added to a ViewGroup once. You need to be making ***new*** TextViews and adding those to your LinearLayout. You can do this either via the TextView constructor or a LayoutInflater with a separate xml layout.